# Yii Framework project gives 404 Errors

Tags: php, yii, yii2, php-7

I am trying to install someone's github project who used Yii.  I am getting 404 not found errors and need help fixing it.
My index.php comes up fine.
mydomain.com/
But any urls in subdirectories fail with a 404 not found error.
For instance mydomain.com/stats
I am using lighttpd and php7.  I don't see anything in the logs
for either of those two programs.

Structure is like this:
My root is:
/var/yaamp/web/
The index.php lives there.
Then I have subdirectories called

```
/var/yaamp/web/assets
/var/yaamp/web/extensions
/var/yaamp/web/framework
/var/yaamp/web/images
/var/yaamp/web/yaamp
```

For the most part I think directly referencing files as they are in the directory structure works fine.
I can do mydomain.com/yaamp/modules/stats/test.php

or mydomain.com/images/41.png

But the original developer has lots of links that don't explicitly exist in the structure so I'm not sure why it isn't working.
For instance mydomain.com/stats probably is referring to a file called
/var/yaamp/web/yaamp/modules/stats/index.php

I get an error 500 when I try it like this:
mydomain.com/yaamp/modules/stats/index.php

also in that folder is a file that may be important called StatsController.php

The relevant section of my lighttpd.conf looks like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "mydomain.com" {
    server.document-root = "/var/yaamp/web"
    url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^(.*)/([0-9]+)$" => "index.php?r=$1&id=$2",
    "^(.*)\?(.*)" => "index.php?r=$1&$2",
            "^(.*)" => "index.php?r=$1",
            "." => "index.php"
    )
url.access-deny = ( "~", ".dat", ".log" )
}
```

I just don't know what to do next.  Please help!

Comment: i dont think it is yii2 isnt it

Comment: Well I found out the problem.  It wasn't really a yii issue.  It was that the lighttpd.conf file had commented out mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Yii have a system of routes. Creating virtual urls to actions inside controllers.

You don't need to call `mydomain.com/yaamp/modules/stats/index.php` `mydomain.com/yaamp/modules/stats/index.php` should work, but is hard to tell anything without look te code.

The default of a route in Yii works something like this. The url `domain.com/stats` link to a controller called `Stats` with a action called `index`.

Here the more info about how Yii handles a request:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-overview.html